# Android. Java. Условие в Random.nextInt();

Tags: java, android, случайные-числа

Подскажите, как можно заменить мою проверку, на такую, чтобы она выполнялась сразу при рандоме в первой строке, если это возможно:

```
int type = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
while (type == previousType) {
  type = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
} 
previousType = type;
```

Если не понятно зачем это, то при первом выполнении это определяет тип уровня, а при повторном так же определяет его, но уже тип получается не равный предыдущему, то есть чтобы не было подряд одинаковых. Надеюсь не запутал.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, это то, что Вы имели в виду:

```
while ((type = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1) == previousType) {
       type = new Random().nextInt(10) + 1;
}   
previousType = type;
```

Answer (score 1):

1)Не надо каждый раз создавать `new Random()` - это расточительство.

2)А проверку лучше заточить в отдельную функцию, к тому же цикл должен быть постфиксный.

3)При первом вызове функции лучше вызвать как: `getNextType(-1)`

```
private int getNextType(int previousType) {
   Random random = new Random();
   do {
       type = random.nextInt(10)+1;
   } while (type == previousType);
   return type;
}
```